# $ not a function in flexslider

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I want to stop autoslider in flexslider module.I caught

> undefined TypeError:$ is not a function

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
    $('#testvideo').flexslider({ //undefined TypeError:$ is not a function
        slideshow: false
    });
});
```

How to fix the error

Comment: Change `function($)` to `function()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i stop auto sliding in my flexslider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849075/how-do-i-stop-auto-sliding-in-my-flexslider)

Answer (score 2):

The reference to jQuery - the $ function in this case - is not passed as a parameter. The function gets the event object instead. By specifying it in the parameters list, you're overwriting it. There are multiple avenues to fix this.

If you're not using [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), it can be easily fixed by removing $ from the function's definition: `jQuery(window).load(function() {`. If you do, then you can either use `jQuery()` instead of `$` as such

```
jQuery(window).load(function(event) {
jQuery('#testvideo').flexslider({ //undefined TypeError:$ is not a function
   slideshow: false
 });
});
```

or wrap everything in a IIFE:

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
    $('#testvideo').flexslider({ //undefined TypeError:$ is not a function
       slideshow: false
     });
    });
})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: You should leave a comment when you `-1` a post, explaining why you think it's wrong.

Comment: Do you set any other properties on the slider or do you have any errors in the console?